# I have 100 videos that I uploaded to YouTube. How can I add a prefix in the titles of those 100 videos at once?

Tags: youtube

I have 100 videos that I uploaded to YouTube. How can I add a prefix in the titles of those 100 videos at once? I couldn't find the option YouTube Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the videos from the video manager. Click edit. Then click title. Then you will see a screen that can add a title prefix to front or back. Check the screenshot below for reference which I did from my account. Click update after doing the changes.

[image]